# Apaches mod_rewrite issues

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues with apaches mod_rewrite. I'm wanting to make clean urls with my php application but it doesn't seem to give the results i'm expecting.

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})$ /project/index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]{4})$ /project/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

To make it so when I view, `http://localhost/user/project/system`, it would be the equivelant of viewing `http://localhost/user/project/index.php?q=system`

Instead of getting any results I just get a typical 404 error.

I've also just checked to see if mod_rewrite works by replace my .htaccess code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

And it properly redirects me here, so mod_rewrite is definitely working.

The root path to my project is `/home/user/public_html/project`

The the url used to view my project is `http://localhost/user/project`

If anymore information is required let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the leading `/` in the target path?

Comment: Where is that .htaccess file located? If already within the project/ folder, then mentioning it in the RewriteRule will not work.

Comment: @Emil - From what I can see, nothing.

Comment: @mario - It is, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `.htaccess` file is indeed located in the `project/` subdirectory already, then don't mention it in the RewriteRule again. Remove it:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})$ /project/index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L]
# no "project/" here
```

Rules always pertain to the current local filename mapping.

Else experiment with a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).

Comment: I've tried just going from here:
    `RewriteEngine on`
    `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$ index.php?component=$1[L]`
But it only let's me have one interger or character(doesnt matter whic), if i have anymore it gives me a 404 page.
so `http://localhost/user/project/f`, `http://localhost/user/project/1`, `http://localhost/user/project/Q` all work, `http://localhost/user/project/system` does not.

Comment: This has been explained to you before. Use a quantifier `+`

Comment: yes, you're right. sorry for my stupidity today. i don't know much about regex at all. i've added + to the outside of the ending bracket and that seems to do the trick. thanks for your time and help, i greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
RewriteRule ^/project/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})$ /project/index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^/project/([0-9]{4})$ /project/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The '^project' means "start of line is 'project'" but the start is a '/project', so you need to include the starting slash (i.e. '^/project...').

---

Sorry, missed the system bit (and the user bit). Was concentrating on the slash.

```
RewriteRule ^/user/project/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /user/project/index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^/user/project/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /user/project/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Should have you right.

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me a 404 error page. I've uploaded it on my webhosts server and it is a 404 there as well. I wanted to check and see if it could possibly have been my set up.

Comment: Since it was my bad on having it only match numbers with 4 digits do I just remove the `{4}` from the regex?

Comment: If you don't want to match with 4 characters, make it a * i.e. [a-x]*

Answer (score 0):

You have [0-9]{4} in your regex which will only match numbers of 4 digits. "system", however, is not a number of 4 digits, and therefore does not match.

You can use something like [^/]+ instead.

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([0-9]{2})$ /index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Don't know if the second parameter should be a number with 2 digits or not.

Edit: I also added "user" at the beginning now.

Edit2: Okay, I thought you were in the root htdocs with your htaccess. So remove "project" and "user" if you are in "project" with the .htaccess.

Comment: no, it shouldn't matter there either. that was my fault, the problem is that that was not explained in the tutorial. also I posted the wrong code, 0-9 is meant to be a-z. i tried your code though, I received a 404.

Comment: Another thing I see is you have "user" in front. I updated my answer, please try this.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's just my server somehow, the way I have my directories symbolicly linked may be causing this or something not set properly in httpd.conf. I tried your code and it should work but it still gave me a 404. If .htacess is placed inside /user/projects is there a way to just determine that directory as the main path and ingore having to define the user and project directory?

Comment: Have you tried removing ^ at the beginning? (without "user" then, I guess). Just start with project.

Comment: [a-z]+ matches any of a-z with at least one character. [a-z]{4} matches only 4 character strings. [^/]+ matches a string of at least one character which does not contain a slash /.

Comment: If you want to learn more about regex, I recommend you the book "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl. Very good one.